# How to consume a REST service the right way?

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, service, microservices

I want to create a multi-module rest service project with spring-boot containing api and impl modules.

The api module should contain the model (dtos and entities), and the service interfaces which will contain the methods that can be called on this service. For example `UserEntity`, `DTO` that return information which is related somehow to the user and `UserService` interface that contain methods register and login of the user. Then in the impl module i want to have a dependency to the api module and i want to provide the implementation of this methods. I think this module should as well contain RestController which will be annotated with RequestMapping and RestController annotations and should map the requests to the service to the correct method implementation. After that i want to create a client-side project that will contain the UI. I want again to add the dependency only to the api module. Then I want in the client project to inject as beans service instances.

For example i want to have bean config class in which i want to provide the url of the service-impl module and i want to create instances of the service-api interfaces via rest template or web client. For example i want a method that return UserService instance annotated as bean which contains

```
return restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:8082", UserService.class);
```

Is this the right way of doing providing implementation to the api without depending to the impl module? Then I want to consume this bean as a normal service in the client project.

For example

```
userService.register(user)
```

However when i try to do that the client project cannot find the service and returns 404. In the same time the service project is running on port 8082. Im not quite sure what i am doing wrong. I am pretty new in the rest services and Im not quite sure if my approach is good or bad. Im not quite sure how this initilizing the service as a bean in the client project from IP address works.

```
@Bean
public UserService userService() {
    return new RestTemplate().getForObject("http://localhost:8082/", UserService.class);
}
```

Again it result a 404 error.

Comment: It's better to understand spring boot architecture first without diving into it directly. Some good resources are: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot and https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-creating

Comment: how you have mapped request http://localhost:8082/ in rest controller?

Comment: I have annotated the controller with : RestController and RequestMapping annotations
Then i have a constructor like this: 

    @Autowired
    public UserController(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

And I have an method like this:
public UserService messageService() {
        return userService;
    }

Comment: @Sefwan Shaikh thank you for the resources. I have read some matterials but no tutorial that i got contains multi-module architecture. I will check yours now. Thank you!

Comment: Please check the following github source https://github.com/pandiyan90/microservice-blog